# Multiple chroots in ubuntu for PHP/MySQL hosting

Tags: ubuntu, php, nginx, varnish, chroot

We have a server, Core i7, 24GB RAM we run some of our own applications on.

I want to offer some clients PHP/MySQL hosting on that server.

Is it feaseable and possible to create a chroot for each client with it's own nginx/php cgi/mysql install?

We have varnish running on the server.

My idea is to configure varnish to forward requests to the chrooted nginx we'd have for each client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While certainly possible, but you might want to check out Lxc http://lxc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, I think that's more along the line of what I was looking to do, but didn't know it existed.